# Android Graphs: Customizing the Grid in GraphView

Tags: android, api, graph, charts

Hey everybody: I am currently integrating the GraphView library in my android project. I was wondering, if the size of the grid could be adjusted. Also, can the label size be changed? The numbers are really small and hard to read. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the source code. Clone it from github and use it as Android library.

The code is really easy to understand.
For example to change the label size/color/more just modify it there:
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/com/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView.java#L213

Good luck

Comment: the new version has completely different source code. now you have to check here https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview/GridLabelRenderer.java

Answer (score 2):

U can change the label size using the below code

```
   //setting the minimum and maximum values for x and y axis
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(12);
    graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinY(0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxY(6);


    //number of labels on x nd y axis
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(7);
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumVerticalLabels(7);
```